# Add available_date to cart.php in Prestashop

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6

I want to add the product.available_date to the cart in Prestashop 1.6.

I added the following line in shopping-cart-product-line-tpl

```
{if isset($product.available_date) && $product.available_date > $smarty.now|date_format:'%Y-%m-%d'}
  <span id="availability_date_label">{l s='Availability date:'}</span>
  <span id="availability_date_value">
    {if Validate::isDate($product.available_date)}
    {dateFormat date=$product.available_date full=false}
    {/if}
  </span>
```

But I found out that the available_date is not set in the Cart.php

I found the following function in cart.php

> public function getProducts($refresh = false, $id_product = false, $id_country = null)

that I think is used to collect the product data and it has a sql->select like this:

```
    // Build query
    $sql = new DbQuery();

    // Build SELECT
    $sql->select('cp.`id_product_attribute`, cp.`id_product`, cp.`quantity` AS cart_quantity, cp.id_shop, pl.`name`, p.`is_virtual`,
                    pl.`description_short`, pl.`available_now`, pl.`available_later`, **(added p.`available_date` here)**,product_shop.`id_category_default`, p.`id_supplier`,
                    p.`id_manufacturer`, product_shop.`on_sale`, product_shop.`ecotax`, product_shop.`additional_shipping_cost`,
                    product_shop.`available_for_order`, product_shop.`price`, product_shop.`active`, product_shop.`unity`, product_shop.`unit_price_ratio`,
                    stock.`quantity` AS quantity_available, p.`width`, p.`height`, p.`depth`, stock.`out_of_stock`, p.`weight`,
                    p.`date_add`, p.`date_upd`, IFNULL(stock.quantity, 0) as quantity, pl.`link_rewrite`, cl.`link_rewrite` AS category,
                    CONCAT(LPAD(cp.`id_product`, 10, 0), LPAD(IFNULL(cp.`id_product_attribute`, 0), 10, 0), IFNULL(cp.`id_address_delivery`, 0)) AS unique_id, cp.id_address_delivery,
                    product_shop.advanced_stock_management, ps.product_supplier_reference supplier_reference');

    // Build FROM
    $sql->from('cart_product', 'cp');

    // Build JOIN
    $sql->leftJoin('product', 'p', 'p.`id_product` = cp.`id_product`');
    $sql->innerJoin('product_shop', 'product_shop', '(product_shop.`id_shop` = cp.`id_shop` AND product_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product`)');
    $sql->leftJoin('product_lang', 'pl', '
        p.`id_product` = pl.`id_product`
        AND pl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('pl', 'cp.id_shop')
    );

    $sql->leftJoin('category_lang', 'cl', '
        product_shop.`id_category_default` = cl.`id_category`
        AND cl.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->id_lang.Shop::addSqlRestrictionOnLang('cl', 'cp.id_shop')
    );

    $sql->leftJoin('product_supplier', 'ps', 'ps.`id_product` = cp.`id_product` AND ps.`id_product_attribute` = cp.`id_product_attribute` AND ps.`id_supplier` = p.`id_supplier`');

    // @todo test if everything is ok, then refactorise call of this method
    $sql->join(Product::sqlStock('cp', 'cp'));

    // Build WHERE clauses
    $sql->where('cp.`id_cart` = '.(int)$this->id);
    if ($id_product) {
        $sql->where('cp.`id_product` = '.(int)$id_product);
    }
    $sql->where('p.`id_product` IS NOT NULL');

    // Build ORDER BY
    $sql->orderBy('cp.`date_add`, cp.`id_product`, cp.`id_product_attribute` ASC');

    if (Customization::isFeatureActive()) {
        $sql->select('cu.`id_customization`, cu.`quantity` AS customization_quantity');
        $sql->leftJoin('customization', 'cu',
            'p.`id_product` = cu.`id_product` AND cp.`id_product_attribute` = cu.`id_product_attribute` AND cu.`id_cart` = '.(int)$this->id);
        $sql->groupBy('cp.`id_product_attribute`, cp.`id_product`, cp.`id_shop`');
    } else {
        $sql->select('NULL AS customization_quantity, NULL AS id_customization');
    }

    if (Combination::isFeatureActive()) {
        $sql->select('
            product_attribute_shop.`price` AS price_attribute, product_attribute_shop.`ecotax` AS ecotax_attr,
            IF (IFNULL(pa.`reference`, \'\') = \'\', p.`reference`, pa.`reference`) AS reference,
            (p.`weight`+ pa.`weight`) weight_attribute,
            IF (IFNULL(pa.`ean13`, \'\') = \'\', p.`ean13`, pa.`ean13`) AS ean13,
            IF (IFNULL(pa.`upc`, \'\') = \'\', p.`upc`, pa.`upc`) AS upc,
            IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.`minimal_quantity`, product_shop.`minimal_quantity`) as minimal_quantity,
            IF(product_attribute_shop.wholesale_price > 0,  product_attribute_shop.wholesale_price, product_shop.`wholesale_price`) wholesale_price
        ');

        $sql->leftJoin('product_attribute', 'pa', 'pa.`id_product_attribute` = cp.`id_product_attribute`');
        $sql->leftJoin('product_attribute_shop', 'product_attribute_shop', '(product_attribute_shop.`id_shop` = cp.`id_shop` AND product_attribute_shop.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`)');
    } else {
        $sql->select(
            'p.`reference` AS reference, p.`ean13`,
            p.`upc` AS upc, product_shop.`minimal_quantity` AS minimal_quantity, product_shop.`wholesale_price` wholesale_price'
        );
    }

    $sql->select('image_shop.`id_image` id_image, il.`legend`');
    $sql->leftJoin('image_shop', 'image_shop', 'image_shop.`id_product` = p.`id_product` AND image_shop.cover=1 AND image_shop.id_shop='.(int)$this->id_shop);
    $sql->leftJoin('image_lang', 'il', 'il.`id_image` = image_shop.`id_image` AND il.`id_lang` = '.(int)$this->id_lang);

    $result = Db::getInstance()->executeS($sql);
```

I tried adding `p.available_date` in the query and got the date, but not if a product have a combination. Then it added same date on both combinations.

Anyone got any idea on how to make it work for combinations as well?

Answer (score 0):

Above query will fetch data by joining cart table with product, category and manufacturer table. There is no join combination in the above query. But you have noticed that system is fetching **id_product_attribute** with each product from above query and if combination feature is active into store then system already has condition to get combination data as shown below:

```
if (Combination::isFeatureActive()) {  
   $sql->select('
            product_attribute_shop.`price` AS price_attribute, product_attribute_shop.`ecotax` AS ecotax_attr,
            IF (IFNULL(pa.`reference`, \'\') = \'\', p.`reference`, pa.`reference`) AS reference,
            (p.`weight`+ pa.`weight`) weight_attribute,
            IF (IFNULL(pa.`ean13`, \'\') = \'\', p.`ean13`, pa.`ean13`) AS ean13,
            IF (IFNULL(pa.`isbn`, \'\') = \'\', p.`isbn`, pa.`isbn`) AS isbn,
            IF (IFNULL(pa.`upc`, \'\') = \'\', p.`upc`, pa.`upc`) AS upc,
            IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.`minimal_quantity`, product_shop.`minimal_quantity`) as minimal_quantity,
            IF(product_attribute_shop.wholesale_price > 0,  product_attribute_shop.wholesale_price, product_shop.`wholesale_price`) wholesale_price
        ');
        $sql->leftJoin('product_attribute', 'pa', 'pa.`id_product_attribute` = cp.`id_product_attribute`');
        $sql->leftJoin('product_attribute_shop', 'product_attribute_shop', '(product_attribute_shop.`id_shop` = cp.`id_shop` AND product_attribute_shop.`id_product_attribute` = pa.`id_product_attribute`)');  
}  else {
        $sql->select(
            'p.`reference` AS reference, p.`ean13`, p.`isbn`,
            p.`upc` AS upc, product_shop.`minimal_quantity` AS minimal_quantity, product_shop.`wholesale_price` wholesale_price'
        );
}
```

To get the **combination available date**, just add the available date column in select query as shown in below code:

```
$sql->select('pa.available_date as combination_available_date, 
        product_attribute_shop.`price` AS price_attribute, product_attribute_shop.`ecotax` AS ecotax_attr,
        IF (IFNULL(pa.`reference`, \'\') = \'\', p.`reference`, pa.`reference`) AS reference,
        (p.`weight`+ pa.`weight`) weight_attribute,
        IF (IFNULL(pa.`ean13`, \'\') = \'\', p.`ean13`, pa.`ean13`) AS ean13,
        IF (IFNULL(pa.`isbn`, \'\') = \'\', p.`isbn`, pa.`isbn`) AS isbn,
        IF (IFNULL(pa.`upc`, \'\') = \'\', p.`upc`, pa.`upc`) AS upc,
        IFNULL(product_attribute_shop.`minimal_quantity`, product_shop.`minimal_quantity`) as minimal_quantity,
        IF(product_attribute_shop.wholesale_price > 0,  product_attribute_shop.wholesale_price, product_shop.`wholesale_price`) wholesale_price
    ');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it didnt help anything. Still get the same date on attributes if i fill in a date on one of the combination.

Comment: Do i maybe need to do anything else in tpl file aswell to call the date for combination?

Comment: Hi, can you please show your tpl file content so that I can clear about data rendering

Comment: Hi! You can see the file here, http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07767455751519878092